# Python random module doesn't randomize more than once

Tags: python, tkinter, random

in this code there are two Random Number Generators. One in the first line, the other in the function `btn_yes`.

Both RNG's work fine, the `print(nb)` directly after the generator in the function `btn_yes` displays a random number like it should.

However, when `btn_press` is activated after `btn_yes` was activated (like it should in the program), the value of `nb` doesn't change, no matter how often i execute `btn_yes`. `btn_press` just uses the same number that was generated by the first RNG.

What am I missing?

```
nb = random.randrange(0, 11)

def btn_press():
    guess = int(entry.get())
    print(guess)
    if guess < nb:
        answ["text"] = "Higher!"
    elif guess > nb:
        answ["text"] = "Lower!"
    elif guess == nb:
        answ["text"] = "Correct!"
        btn2["bg"] = "#FF6C6C"
        btn3["bg"] = "#32FF00"
        
def btn_no():
    window.destroy()

def btn_yes():
    answ["text"] = "Next Round! Type in a new number!"
    btn2["bg"] = "#464646"
    btn3["bg"] = "#464646"
    nb = random.randrange(0, 11)
    entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    print(nb)
```

Comment: Make sure your code is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your sample needs to define imports and globals(?) like `entry`. I'd guess it has to do with the cursor/positioning in `entry`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that when you change a global variable inside a function, you need to put `global <variablename>` as the first line in the function. Otherwise, Python assumes you meant to make a *new variable* with that name that *is only in scope inside the function*, and the global variable remains unchanged.

You can see this by `print`ing `nb` inside the function `btn_yes()`; you should see that it has a different value each time (and not the same value as the global `nb`).

In this case, if you put `global nb` as the first line in `btn_yes()`, it should have the desired effect.

See [using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: @Jantro If an answer worked for you, it's courteous to accept it (green checkmark).